# Updates not possible with Prisma and CosmosDB with MongoDB API

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, prisma

I was thrilled to learn about [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) recently and quickly replaced mongoose in my latest project.

Integration was easy & connections are working fine with CosmosDB by using the connection strings.

My issue: seems like I can't update any data, as CosmosDB is throwing a Raw Error:

```
Invalid `prisma.addresses.update()` invocation:


Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: RawError { code: "unknown", message: "Command failed (BadValue): Expected type object but found array.)" } })
```

I'm running the latest MongoDB server version that is available on Azure (4.0) and the update is really basic:

```
await this.prisma.addresses.update({
  where: {
    id: 'something',
  },
  data: {
    city: 'Something'
  }
})
```

Querying and creating documents hasn't caused any issues.

Comment: can you share your schema please?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the schema you need to pass the parameters to your method. Whether it is update, create or delete.

Check for `schema.prisma` under your prisma folder, look for address and check for update parameter.

If you want to understand more about different use cases, you can refer to this [doc](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud)

Also check this [blog](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-nodejs-database-using-prisma-orm/) to get the insights about node.js and prisma.